# Postgres Select subgroup

Tags: sql, postgresql

Wondering if there are any tricks in PG 9.3 that will help me?

```
TableID, CommentID, Comment, Orderid 
 1, 1,  "Jenn, Looks Good", 1
 2, 1,  "Benn, The Doc looks good.",    2
 3, 2,  "Like it",  1
 4, 3,  "Splling",  1
 5, 3,  "Spelling", 2
 6, 3,  "Check the Spelling", 3
```

I've got this table that is comments and rather than updating comments an edit is put in as the next "orderid" for the commentID. I'm looking for a select that will return this:

```
Benn, The Doc looks good.
Like it
Check the Spelling
```

I'm looking for something better looping through each of the commentID if it's possible.

My current solution is to Group by CommentID and then foreach select comment where commentid = ? order by orderid desc limit 1 into a temp and then selecting the temp table.

I was looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12653000/3562373 since I have a parent key that has more info about the comment and came up with:

```
Select comment  
from commentInfo  
inner join ( Select * From  comment order by orderid  desc limit 1 ) on CommentInfo.CommentID = Comment.CommentID 
where commentinf = (The Group of comments I'm interested in)
```

But since the limit applies to whole table it isn't helping me

Comment: People who down vote should be forced to leave a reason why. I would love to know how to ask a propor question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is to return the latest version for every CommentID (that is the one with highest OrderID) then you can find the latest version in a derived table and join with that:

```
select t.* from table t
join (
    select CommentID, max(orderid) orderid
    from table group by CommentID
) b on b.CommentID = t.CommentID and b.orderid = t.Orderid
```